# A question about harmonic function

Tags: elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a harmonic function inside the unit ball $B(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that $|u|\leqslant 1$. Does a function u which satisfies $|\nabla u(0)|>1$ exist? If not, please prove that $|\nabla u(0)|\leqslant1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  answer is  "Yes" by the following  harmonic  analogy of  Schwarz  lemma:

See  Proposition 1.5.  of this  paper  which says  that $4/\pi$  is  a  sharp upper  bound.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4905.pdf

Comment: @张旭辉  You are well come!